# What does set -a "Mark variables which are modified or created for export" actually mean?

Tags: bash, set

The help text for `set -a` is somewhat cryptic to me, but maybe i just don't understand what bash is doing behind the scenes with variables. Can someone explain why "marking" variables is needed (what are "unmarked" variables)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bash man-page uses a slightly different wording for this: *Each variable or function that is created or modified is  given  the  export attribute and marked for export to the environment of subsequent commands.* This sounds more clear to me. It means:

Each variable you define in your script, is placed in the environment of any child process you create, and each function you define is also available to each bash-child-process you create.

Comment: doesn't this sound like bad practice of polluting the global environment ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga : Yes, and I would never do it.  I find this bash feature of questionable value. One application I could think of it, is, if you have a file with shell-style name-value associations (`NAME1=VALUE1`), and you want to import these associations into your bash process, but also export them. In this case, you could do a `set -a`, then source the file (with all risks involved), and then do a `set +a` to turn off auto-export.

Comment: Thanks @user1934428 ! That's exactly the context in which I discovered `set -a`, before sourcing a `.env` file with definitions of variables.